# Change border radius of sticky navbar to zero on scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to find a js code to make a navigation bar change from 35px 35px 0 0 border radius to 0 0 0 0 when it starts to scroll. Any insight? I have very little JS experience and am feeling stuck.

css:

```
    .top { 
    background: var(--drk);
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0px 30px;
    color: var(--lfont);
    line-height: 50px;
    font-family: PT-Mono;
    border-radius: 35px 35px 0 0;
    width: 1140px;
    top: 0; 
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 99;
    }

.board { 
background-color: var(--mid);
min-height: 1000px;
border-radius: 35px;
}
```

html

```
<div class="board"><div class="top">

<x>♡</x> welcome!

</div></div>
```

Comment: `$(document).scroll(function () {$('.top').css('border-radius', '0')})`

Comment: @Justinas Do you see the use of jQuery here?

Comment: @HarshitRastogi No, don't see any of jQuery, JS, Java, Bash or other programming language.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it and also reset it when scrolled to top:

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
  var doc = document.documentElement;
  var top = (window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop) - (doc.clientTop || 0);

  var header = document.getElementsByClassName("top")[0]
  if (top > 15) {
    header.style.borderRadius = "0 0 0 0";
  } else {
    header.style.borderRadius = "35px 35px 0 0";
  }
});
```

```css
.top {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0px 30px;
  color: yellow;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-family: PT-Mono;
  border-radius: 35px 35px 0 0;
  width: 1140px;
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 99;
}

.board {
  background-color: purple;
  min-height: 1000px;
  border-radius: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="board">
  <div class="top">

    <x>♡</x> welcome!

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a scroll event listener and the change the style of the element on scroll event

```js
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {

    var element = document.getElementById('top');
    
    element.style.borderRadius = '0 0 0 0';
});
```

```css
 .top { 
    background: gray;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0px 30px;
    color: var(--lfont);
    line-height: 50px;
    font-family: PT-Mono;
    border-radius: 35px 35px 0 0;
    width: 1140px;
    top: 0; 
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 99;
    }

.board { 
background-color: var(--mid);
min-height: 1000px;
border-radius: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="board"><div id="top" class="top">

<x>♡</x> welcome!

</div></div>
```